# Earth rotation warps the mesh instead of rotating

Tags: mesh, uv, 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm new to blender and followed this tutorial: https://youtu.be/b0N_Bz8amlw and I'm able to produce a mesh plane with a bend:

[image]

But when I press "R + X" to rotate on X axis I get the following warp instead of a rotation:

[image]

I'm wondering why is this happening and what is the cause of the problem?

I guess an additional education point would also be why do some youtube videos use UV sphere whilst other's use mesh plane bends to create a sphere, I can't seem to find out a simple explanation of the pro's and con's of each. (Perhaps this rotation is a con for a mesh plane?)

Comment: Hi :). The rotation is confusing the *Simple Deform* modifier. Either parent the empty to your *Plane mesh* or apply the *Deform* modifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have simple deform that blends your object around empty. Then you rotate the object empty stays in place, that makes changes in position of empty relative to object. As a result, object blends in the different way. You can parent empty to object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) or apply modifiers to prevent this behavior.

You can also use **Add** -> **Mesh** -> **UV sphere** instead of this complex structure, which creates a sphere like yours.

Answer (score 1):

...If you forget the Empty, and, in Edit Mode, align the **mesh**: short-side up the Z of its own Object Axes (displayed in this illustration), and long-side along the X, then a 180 X-bend followed by a 360 Z-bend will work.

[image]

Modifiers are in the modified object's space by default, so they stay aligned to the object when it is rotated,translated, or scaled.